# mysql rank multiple row specific criteria

Tags: mysql

Ihave this table

[image]

i want to rank each row but only for specific criteria
in this case based on cust_id, month, year, transaction_no
and the output to be like this.

[image]

the criteria is by the same cust_id, month, year.

what is the query? thank you.

Comment: What are the specific criteria?

Comment: What you have tried? what is the problem in your query?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then `ROW_NUMBER` can be used here:

```sql
SELECT
    cust_id,
    month,
    year,
    transaction_no,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY year, month) `rank`
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    cust_id DESC,
    year,
    month;
```

Depending on the exact ranking behavior you actually want (not clear from your sample data), you might want to replace `ROW_NUMBER` with either `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK`.

**Edit:**

On MySQL 5, we might be able to use correlated count queries to find the rank numbers:

```sql
SELECT
    cust_id,
    month,
    year,
    transaction_no,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM yourTable t2
     WHERE t2.cust_id = t1.cust_id AND
           (t2.year < t1.year OR t2.year = t1.year AND t2.month <= t1.month)) `rank`
FROM yourTable t1
ORDER BY
    cust_id DESC,
    year,
    month;
```

This approach would work assuming that, for each `cust_id`, the `year` and `month` value combinations would always be unique.

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8d238982ddab44bdde5a1672f93625ed) of the second 5.7 compatible version of the query.

[image: screen capture from 5.7 version of the query]

Comment: unfortunately my engine still using mysql 5. I have found this "ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION" in all over internet, but mysql denied it because its an old mysql. Do you any conventional way to solve my problem?

Comment: There are a few workarounds you could try, all of which would probably have worse performance than my answer.  I strongly recommend upgrading to MySQL 8, as 5+ will not be supported for much longer.

Answer (score -1):

Well you must define the relational ranking table based on cust_id and join those table